# How to match the following in karate

Tags: karate

My database output is as follows `{web,app}`

Output from response is as follows  `["web","app"]`

How to match these two in karate?

Comment: voting to close. I'm the author of karate and this question doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database output `{web,app}` doesn't follow any proper data structure.

it would be difficult to iterate over this.

I assume it is a `String`

Edit:

if it is a string you write a js to get that as a convenient data structure (array)

```
* def pList = function(x) { return x.replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",") }
```

now pass your particular value to this function and it would give you an array of values which you can easily `match`

Comment: This is how my database output for one query looks like `[
  [
    59,
    2018-10-30 13:52:46.19584,
    2018-10-30 08:22:46.19584,
    false,
    "oak-1",
    "dada",
    2018-10-30,
    2018-11-04,
    2018-10-30,
    2018-11-04,
    2000.0,
    0.0,
    true,
    "NRP",
    "direct",
    {web,app},
    "abhishek.malani@treehotels.com",
    "1"
  ]
]`

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only way to store a list in postgres DB

Comment: then string it is, i have updated my answer pls check