# how to use karate.match in a conditional loop

Tags: karate

How can I implement the following

```
* eval if(TestCaseType == "negative") karate.match(messageConstructedFromRequestData_N1,messageFromApiResponse_N1)

* eval if(TestCaseType == "positive") karate.match(messageConstructedFromRequestData_P1,messageFromApiResponse_P1)
```

I basically want to match variables when a certain condition is matched.
I tried this

```
* eval if(TestCaseType == "negative-2") result = karate.match(messageConstructedFromRequestData_N2,responseMessage_N2)
```

When I print result i get it as "true" but I cannot assign this to a variable and then assert the result. Something like this

```
* def y = result
* match y == { pass: true, message: null }
```

Comment: done! apologies.

Comment: this one also please: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53079269/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over-engineering your tests. Keep it simple. Split into multiple steps. For example:

```
* def first = { available: true, collection: true }
* def second = { code: 'foo', message: 'bar' }
* def testType = 2

* def response = second
* def expected = testType == 2 ? { code: '#string', 'message': '#string' } : { available: '#boolean', collection: '#boolean' }
* match response == expected
```

Find the section on "Conditional Logic" in the docs carefully. And remember if you really want, you can call another feature (or Java code) to simplify things.

But I honestly think you are over-complicating your tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
def conditional =
  """
  function() {if(result.pass){
  var arr = []
    arr[0] = karate.match(response.businessData.productRule.productName, '#string').pass;
    arr[1] = karate.match(response.businessData.productRule.productName, '#stdfsring').pass;
    return arr;  
    }
  }
  """
  * def callFunction = call conditional
  * print callFunction
  * match callFunction !contains false
```